# Gmail Contextual gadget is not visible when I open mail

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We have created project using console.developers.google.com , and after creating the project we selected appropriate API which are needed for working with Gmail Contextual Gadget,

We configured everything like, Url Extractors, Gadget Url, Param Name and values according to google api given names and values

But after launching the app we are unable to see the gadget in Gmail Mail.
I tried '&nogadgetcache=1' also but after using this also I am unable to see the gadget in my Gmail.

Normally The gadget is to be appear on every email, I have set all scopes and everything.

Is there any thing need to be configured extra on Marketplace please help me out

Comment: Are you using Google for work account or gmail account? Gmail Contextual gadget works only for work account. Also, are you using resuing gadget spec? If so, are you following the steps here  https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?csw=1

Comment: It is working fine. Issue is one of the param values ' * ', Then I changed it to ' .* ' thats it!.  it is working fine.